# how can Disable options for keyboard and mouse to wake up the host by c#

Tags: c#

how can Disable options for keyboard and mouse to wake up the host by c#
when the computer go to stanby and hibernate, not allow to wake the computer by mouse movement or clicking on the keyboard

Manual can do it this way: control panel-> Device Manager -> keyboard/mouse -> properties -> Power Management

Comment: cut their keyboard and mouse cable... People can help you, if you give more details.

Comment: when the computer go to stanby and hibernate, not allow to wake the computer by mouse movement or clicking on the keyboard

Comment: Then after that want you want to do ?

Comment: I want to set this setting through c# code

Answer (score 0):

Usually these settings are made in BIOS so that's going to be difficult to achieve.

Comment: Manual can do it this way: control panel-> Device Manager -> keyboard/mouse -> properties -> Power Management

Comment: Then why don't you do it through Group Policy?

Comment: How can I make it through Group Policy?

Comment: Do you know anything about Group Policy?

Comment: Why don't you tell everyone more details of why you wish to do this and why you are so focussed on doing sysadmin in C#.

Comment: I write a tool that make set-up automation to new computers, Fixed settings always set our company

Comment: You should just do this with group policy. Perhaps one of your company's sysadmins could explain what group policy is.

Answer (score 0):

I am not using Win 7 So I can't say exactly.

In windows most of the settings of Group Policy and Control Panel is added in Registry. If you are able to set from Control Panel.

then, you have to create [Registry Key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.aspx) in your C# code.

Comment: how can I do it by registry Key?